# Tomcat 9 returning 404 for audio file

Tags: tomcat, audio, http-status-code-404

I just upgraded a legacy application from Tomcat 7 to Tomcat 9. I'm facing a weird issue with audio files playback.

When loading a page that contains an audio file. First time Tomcat returns 404 error but if reloading the page, audio file is loaded properly and no error from Tomcat.

I'm using html 5 audio control to display the file.

All other static resources(images, css and js files) are working without any issues. Only audio files are having this issue.

I've spent days trying to solve this but no luck :(

I would really appreciate any guidance to solve this issue.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Here is additional information:

I enabled the logs for DefaultServlet in Tomcat. Follwong is the log entry when I try to open the audio file first time.
I can see 404 being returned from server in Chrome dev tools.
**06-Mar-2024 20:12:50.747 INFO DefaultServlet.serveResource:  Serving resource '/wav/2B916004DFE94FA40446429E1671C893_0001053.mp3' headers and data**

Following is the log for 2nd attempt. This time audio is available and playable in browser.
**06-Mar-2024 20:13:00.371 INFO DefaultServlet.serveResource:  Serving resource '/wav/2B916004DFE94FA40446429E1671C893_0001053.mp3' headers and data
06-Mar-2024 20:13:01.372 INFO DefaultServlet.serveFile:  contentType='audio/mpeg'**

Here is the audio control code:

```
<div id="audioContainer" style="height:65px; width:100%; visibility:visible; ">
   <div id="jobAudio" style="height:45px; width: 100%; left:0px; bottom:0;" >
      <audio controls controlsList="nodownload" style="width: 100%;" >
        <source src="/wav/2B916004DFE94FA40446429E1671C893_0001053.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" >
      </audio>
   </div>      
</div>
```

I've tried relative path and full path but result is same in both cases.

Comment: Show us the tomcat logs please, and also header details from Postman testing.